# How to share encrypted data from SQL Server to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, encryption, ssis

I need to lift data from SQL Server using SSIS, some of the data need to be encrypted before writing to csv's... the data then needs to be decrypted and loaded into a MYSQL destination. I can switch on encryption on the SQL server side but i'm unsure how to pass the key/decryption logic to the MYSQL developers.

Tried writing the encrypted data (hashed) to csv but stuck!

Thanks a lot

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8wgW.png)

Comment: Why using two different databases system to begin with? Besides [MySQL Enterprise Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html) only supports encryption which looks more or less like [SQL Server Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017)..

Comment: ... If you don't want the MySQL developers to get the real data you can offcource [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) the tables data with fictional generated data.. A google search ["Obfuscation SQL data"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Obfuscation+SQL+data) might help you out here

Comment: thanks Raymond, MySQL is the new database platform so its a migration piece. The encrypted data is for security during transfer. MYSQL dev's would need to decrypt from csv and load in the true value

Comment: "The encrypted data is for security during transfer. MYSQL dev's would need to decrypt from csv and load in the true value " That means you have working (encryption) code for the SQL Server or in your application right? Which ideally you should share with example data so we can see whats happing.

Comment: just added a pic to the main question piece.. So.. i would be writing the PWEnc field to a csv... MYSQL dev's load the csv but need to know how to decrypt the data back to get the raw PW. Apologies if this doesn't make sense, typically i've encrypted at rest but never shared outside of the db.

Comment: @SQNonymous - is your MySQL also on Windows? If so, is it on the same or different machine than SQL Server?

Comment: @NeilWeicher i believe its on windows, i'll need to confirm but its definitely not on the same box  as the SQL server. It'll be in a different environment completely.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the MySQL server as linked server to your ms sql instance? This way you can directly connect and move data between the two without needing to encrypt the CSVs. Even if you use CSV files, consider encrypting the folder / directory they are stored in as opposed to develop a custom encryption for a data transfer. Btw, hashing is not an encryption. Hashing is one way only, you cannot get the data back.

Comment: @SQNonymous - hopefully this is kosher to mention here. But if your MySQL is also on Windows and if you are willing to consider a third party product that works with both SQL Server and MySQL (on Windows), then please contact me via our [Contact page](https://netlibsecurity.com/contact-us/).

Comment: @NeilWeicher even SSIS can work with both MySQL and ms sql server.